# Scoring procedure for survey responses

Tags: regression, correlation, survey

I have a project to create a scoring procedure for respondents answering multi choice psychological questions based on their behavioural metrics.
So the responses can be treated as categorical variables with 5-6 levels and the metric is continuous.

I am wondering whether it is reasonable to create dummy variables based on the categories and then calculate point-biserial correlations separately for every one of them and then use the correlations as the scores. The problem I see in this approach is the imbalance of the sample sizes together with inter-dependency of the dummy variables.

I could consider fitting a linear regression for every question instead but then I don't have the scores.

Is there any other approach I can use?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that by "5-6 levels and the metric is continuous" you are meaning that that the categories are ordered. If so, the way to address this depends a lot on the theory that was used when generating the questions. If all the questions are meant to measure the same thing, then the way you score it is you first recode the scales so that they are all on a common scale (e.g., with your 6 point scale, replace the values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6 with 1, 1.8, 2.6, 3.4, 4.2, and 5.0, so that all your questions are on the same scale). Then, just sum together the variables, which implicitly treats them all as having the same weight. This may sound overly simple, but it is justified by a concept in psychometrics called Domain Sampling Theory.

If it is suspected that some of the questions may be measuring different things, you then need to either ignore some of the questions (i.e., give them a weight of 0) or create multiple distinct scores. The least technical way of doing this is to create a correlation matrix (google Multitrait-multimethod matrix for instructions on interpretation). The way that most people in practice do it is to use PCA or some variant of factor analysis, as it's much faster.